# Listeners create a new Thread (or something). How to kill it on close a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have a pre-loading fragment code that must run linearly like this:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                Context context = getActivity();
                ArrayList<HashMap> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                            Iterator<?> keys = c.keys();

                            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                                String key = (String) keys.next();
                                item.put(key, c.getString(key));
                            }
                            itemList.add(item);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    TextView desc = (TextView) ncontent.findViewById(R.id.Desc);
                    TextView place = (TextView) ncontent.findViewById(R.id.Place);
                    TextView date = (TextView) ncontent.findViewById(R.id.Date);

                    NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) ncontent.findViewById(R.id.Image);

                    HashMap i = itemList.get(0);

                    desc.setText(i.get("desc").toString());
                    place.setText(i.get("place").toString());
                    date.setText(i.get("date").toString());

                    ImageLoader imageLoader = DataController.getInstance(getActivity()).getImageLoader();
                    image.setImageUrl("http://192.168.0.101/" + i.get("image").toString(), imageLoader);

                    LruBitmapCache lruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
                    lruBitmapCache.getBitmap("http://192.168.0.101/" + i.get("image").toString());
                }
            }, null);

    DataController.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(req);
```

The problem is that when I insert some Listener as the following, this creates a background process when the fragment is closed it continues to run.

```
imageLoader.get("http://192.168.0.101/" + i.get("image").toString(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
@Override
public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
        Image = (ImageView) ncontent.findViewById(R.id.Image);
        Image.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
    }
} });
```

Closing the fragment before the algorithm run returns me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Details3{3e80163e} not attached to Activity
```

I want to kill any procedure that is running when you close the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clear the requests controlled by DataController in the fragment onDestroy life method.

in your onResponse method, you need first check whether context is null or not.